# How i can create a trigger mysql that Prohibit an action either modification or insertion or deletion

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

[image]

i want to prohibit the deletion of fournisseur that he have at least an achats

I use a MySQL database

Comment: Define the fournisseur as foreign key in order to prevent deletes when it exists in the other table.

Comment: The title says prohibit insert,update/delete and the question says prohibit deletion of fournisseur - IS title what you want or is question body what you want? Also please add table definitions as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit other threads (or processes) from modifying the fournisseur table during your action, then you should lock the table (you can lock it only for write actions or for all actions).

Do note that you will need to implement some mutual-exclusion mechanism to sync all clients that **modify** this table (you can lock the table and still allow others to SELECT and JOIN on this table, the others still need to lock the table - but with a **READ** lock).

If another client tries to acquire a **WRITE** lock (because it wants to **modify** a locked table), and the locking thread does not release it in a short time, it will generate an error (timeout).
Such error can be handled in the script (return a specific response so your code knows it reached timeout on the lock statement block).
If it tries to modify a locked table without trying to acquire the lock first, an exception is thrown.

Please see the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)